# Model->save() => Same code different controller but doesn't have same behavior

Tags: php, yii

```
$myModel = new CustomModel();
$myModel->myVal = 'foo';
$myModel->anotherVal = 'bar';
var_dump($myModel);              //return a CustomModel object
var_dump($myModel->validate());  //return true
var_dump($myModel->getErrors()); //return an empty array
var_dump($myModel->save());      //return true
var_dump($myModel->save(false)); //return true
```

This a standard code to use a Model in Yii.
In my originController, the code is exactly like that but nothing in my mySql DB. But in my otherController, everything work fine.

Does someone know how is it possible ? This "bug" drive me crazy !

Thank you everyone :)

Update : 
$myModel->save(false)
already check and same behavior

CustomModel.php

```
<?php

/**
* This is the model class for table "CustomTable".
*
* The followings are the available columns in table 'CustomTable':
* @property integer $customModel_id
* @property integer $customModel_legaldocid
* @property integer $customModel_userid
* @property string $customModel_datelastview
* @property string $customModel_dateaccepted
*/
class CustomModel extends CAActiveRecord
{
    /**
    * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
    * @param string $className active record class name.
    * @return LegalDocumentRead the static model class
    */
public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
{
    return parent::model($className);
}

/**
 * @return string the associated database table name
 */
public function tableName()
{
    return 'CustomTable';
}

/**
 * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
 */
public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('customModel_id, customModel_legaldocid, customModel_userid', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
        array('customModel_datelastview, customModel_dateaccepted', 'safe'),
        // The following rule is used by search().
        // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
        array('customModel_id, customModel_legaldocid, customModel_userid, customModel_datelastview, customModel_dateaccepted', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}

/**
 * @return array relational rules.
 */
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
    );
}

/**
 * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
 */
 public function attributeLabels()
{
    return array(
        'customModel_id' => 'customModel',
        'customModel_legaldocid' => 'customModel Legaldocid',
        'customModel_userid' => 'customModel Userid',
        'customModel_datelastview' => 'customModel Datelastview',
        'customModel_dateaccepted' => 'customModel Dateaccepted',
    );
}

/**
 * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
 * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models based on the search/filter conditions.
   */
public function search()
{
    // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
    // should not be searched.

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('customModel_id',$this->customModel_id);
    $criteria->compare('customModel_legaldocid',$this->customModel_legaldocid);
    $criteria->compare('customModel_userid',$this->customModel_userid);
    $criteria->compare('customModel_datelastview',$this->customModel_datelastview,true);
    $criteria->compare('customModel_dateaccepted',$this->customModel_dateaccepted,true);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: Nothing. Everything works fine except my db doesn't have a new record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Problem solved
Some wrong foreign keys on my mySql db. But yii doesn't say anything about that.
Thank everyone

Answer (score 0):

This could be related  to the fact that you have some validation rule in you CustomModel that are not satisfied in your test ..

try using

```
 $myModel->save(false);
```

or

```
 var_dump($myModel->save(false));
```

and check in your db. If you see a new record  than check you validation rules  or your message error ..

Comment: update your question and add CostumModel code .. and all the code for th action in your sample  .please

Comment: The field  myVal  and anotheVal  are not in your model .. so  please update you test code  with the correct name  ..